# knitr::include_graphics: safe way to read from the project directory?

Tags: r, path, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to make a RMarkdown report using `bookdown::html_document2` to create numbered Fig. 1, Fig. 2, ... across the whole document. Here, I am using both the R-generated and the external figures. [I have found](http://zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/) that using `include_graphics()` will help to generate a proper Fig. X numbers, also including in numbering the external figures.

To get the script to work, I am declaring the `root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file('C:/myRproject'))` while my external figures are located within `C:/myRproject/inImg`. But in this case, R cannot find my external images anymore? Why is this and how can I properly claim the paths for my R Markdown input, and for external figures? Thank you!

Example:

````
---
title: "My awesome title"
author: "me"
date:  "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
knit: (function(input, ...) {
    rmarkdown::render(
      input,
      output_dir = "../outReports",
      output_file = file.path("../outReports", glue::glue('test_{Sys.Date()}'
    )))
  })

---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, tidy = TRUE, tidy.opts = list(comment = FALSE), message = F, warning = F)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=6, fig.height=3) 

library(knitr) 
library(png)

```


```{css, echo=FALSE}
p.caption {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```


```{r setup-root}

knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir =  rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file('C:/myRproject'))

```




```{r read-libs, eval = TRUE, echo=FALSE, include = FALSE, warning = FALSE, error = FALSE }
# rm(list=ls())

getwd()

#### Source paths and functions  -----------------------------------------------
source('myPaths.R')  # already this one I can't find within the directory?
    
# Read pictures as part of teh R chunks
library(knitr) 
library(png)
   

# Read Input data -------------------------------------------------------------------
#getwd()
load(file = "outData/dat1.Rdata")
  
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:


```{r, out.width = "50%", fig.cap = 'Add fig from internet'}
include_graphics("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/MC_Drei-Finger-Faultier.jpg/330px-MC_Drei-Finger-Faultier.jpg")
```


```{r add-extern-plot2, fig.cap = 'my numbered caption'}
# All defaults

img1_path <- "C:/myRproject/inImg/my_extern_fig.png"
img1 <- readPNG(img1_path, native = TRUE, info = TRUE)
attr(img1, "info")


include_graphics(img1_path)
```
````